# Unable to get data in callback in Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to receive data in a subscriber callback written in  an arduino sketch.

I have a publisher publishing on /game_controller , written entirely in roscpp. I trying to get the data published on this topic into arduino. When I try to print the message out to Serial Monitor, I get nothing. I want to know what's amiss?

Arduino Sketch:http://pastebin.com/Mf9yPgn3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33853/unable-to-get-data-in-callback-in-arduino/) by [Blstinne](https://answers.ros.org/users/2371/blstinne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I remember this while testing `rosserial`, you cannot use Serial Monitor and `rosserial` at the same time, as both of them need to connect over the same Serial connection. My node would typically stop responding if I opened the Serial Monitor up.

Instead of using `Serial.println`, I would recommend using the `nh.loginfo`, with the following workaround to print float/double values:

```
float temp = some_float_value;
int temp1 = (temp - (int)temp) * 100;
sprintf(log_msg, "some float value is = %0d.%d", (int)temp, temp1);
nh.loginfo(log_msg);
```

Also remember to remove the `Serial.begin` call, as I believe `nh.init` calls it already.

You should see the output of this log statement from your `rosserial_python` node.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use a mega arduino, you can put the data through Serial1 (or one of the other Serial inputs, Serial2, Serial3, Serial4) and monitor what is happening with the Serial Monitor, as it works through Serial0 (in the arduino code, this is just Serial).

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1